Extracting large password protected 7zip files whilst streaming?
I have a requirement to unzip password protected 7zip files from AWS S3 to a container that has limited space.
The problem is I can't download the entire zip file and then attempt to extract it because there is not enough space assigned to the container and I am unable to change the size of the volume.
I was thinking of streaming and extracting the password protected file on the fly so that only the extracted file takes up space on the container.
At the moment I have attempted to do this with Apache Compress but I have been unsuccessful in doing so.
For instance you can attempt to build a SevenZipFile like so in Apache Compress
SevenZFile.builder()
            .setInputStream(inputStream)
            .setPassword(password)
            .get()

but this throws
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: InputStreamOrigin#getPath() for FileInputStream origin java.io.FileInputStream@3b30eec5


I am able to download the entire file and to extract it but this only works with smaller .7z files due to the space limitation.
I am open to using other Java libraries if they're free for commercial use.

Questions asking us to recommend or find  a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
